# Convert a point on an inclined image to a non-inclined point

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I have an image of an image, where the inner image is inclined and has its own coordinate table (visible on its edges):

[image]

Now I need to convert a point of the actual image to a `(x cm, y cm)` point on the inclined image. Say, I want to know what `(x cm, y cm)` coordinates the bottom left corner (`(0, img.height())`) of the actual image has. That is, if the inner image's coordinate table were to be extrapolated.

I already know:

- The angle `a` of the inclined image
- Two points `p1` and `p2` selected manually from the inclined image
- The cm coordinates `p1cm` and `p2cm` for these two points

I can get the scale of the image by comparing the two points together and getting the ratio between their cm distance and actual distance:

```
double dCmX = p1cm.x() - p2cm.x();
double dCmY = p1cm.y() - p2cm.y();
double dCm = sqrt(pow(dCmX, 2) + pow(dCmY, 2))

double dPointX = p1.x() - p2.x();
double dPointY = p1.y() - p2.y();
double dPoint = sqrt(pow(dPointX, 2) + pow(dPointY, 2))

double scale = dPoint / dCm;
```

But I have no idea how to get the coordinates of the left bottom corner in cm coordinates.

Comment: It's little more than a trig problem. If you can grasp the concepts in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix then this will drop out quite simply. Or consider asking on the mathematics site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of transformation (using only scale and tilt angle) is called Affine Transformation. You might want to use `OpenCV` libraries for simplicity. Then the code is very simple:

```
double scale = dPoint / dCm;  
Point center = Point( img.cols/2, img.rows/2);
Mat warpMat = getRotationMatrix2D( center, angle, scale );
Point2f src[1];
Point2f dst[1];
src[0] = Point2f(src_x, src_y);
transform(src, dst, warpMat);
```

Then you will have your result inside `dst`. You can of course make the `src` array larger and give the [`transform`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#transform) method more points at once.
See also [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/warp_affine/warp_affine.html) for more information about opencv and affine transformation.

---

If you don't want to use `OpenCV` you can still take a look at the documentation pages of [`getRotationMatrix2D`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#getrotationmatrix2d) and [`warpAffine`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#warpaffine) and implement it by yourself, it is quite simple:

[image]

Build the matrix (`warpMat`):

[image]

And then, for each point `(x,y)` build the vector `[x,y,1]` and do a matrix multiplication between `warpMat` and `[x,y,1]`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an [affine Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) which can be carried out by a matrix multiplication.